# T SQL Pivot still one row per pivot column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a pivot table in SQL 2008R2. I'm trying to reproduce and Access Pivot table in SQL. When I run the following script, I get one record for each pivot column instead of one record with two populated pivoted columns.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DataView.MAEID
, DataView.MoYr
, DataView.ChemicalName
, TblCategories.CatDesc
, DataView.[CAS#]
, DataView.HAP
, Sum([SpecAE]/2000) AS [Total SpecAE Tons]
, SUM([SpecAE]) AS [SpecAE]
FROM TblCategories 
INNER JOIN DataView 
ON TblCategories.CatID = DataView.Category
GROUP BY DataView.MAEID
, DataView.MoYr
, DataView.ChemicalName
, DataView.[CAS#]
, DataView.HAP
, TblCategories.CatDesc) TBL
PIVOT (
 Sum([SpecAE])
 FOR CatDesc IN ([INCIINERABLE LIQUIDS], [Supplemental Fuels])
)pvt
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Trying to reproduce an Access Pivot query , not a pivot table.

Comment: Yes, you're producing an individual row for the sum/2000 AND the sum... So you're going to get an individual row for every individual sum/2000. I would suggest removing the sum/2000 in your original query and perhaps figure out what you want to do with the final result set if you still need that information.

Comment: Thanks @ZLK. That was it. I need that value, though,  so I'll just add it to resulting data-set with a sub select.

Comment: Sub Select turned out to be a bad idea. The results took almost 12 minutes to execute. Used an inner join from pvt to DataView. Those results took only 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided sample data, so I'll explain your issue with an example. Let's say I have a very simple table with some very simple values:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    MainColumn INT NOT NULL,
    PivotColumn INT NOT NULL,
    SumColumn INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T VALUES
(1, 1, 10), (1, 1, 20), (1, 1, 30),
(1, 2, 60),
(1, 3, 50),
(2, 1, 10), (2, 1, 15),
(2, 2, 20),
(3, 1, 10),
(3, 2, 10),
(4, 1, 150);
```

If I perform the following query:

```
SELECT MainColumn,
       PivotColumn,
       PivotValue = SUM(SumColumn),
       OtherSum = SUM(SumColumn / 5)
FROM @T
GROUP BY MainColumn, PivotColumn
ORDER BY MainColumn, PivotColumn
```

I get:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| MainColumn | PivotColumn | PivotValue | OtherSum |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|          1 |           1 |         60 |       12 |
|          1 |           2 |         60 |       12 |
|          1 |           3 |         50 |       10 |
|          2 |           1 |         25 |        5 |
|          2 |           2 |         20 |        4 |
|          3 |           1 |         10 |        2 |
|          3 |           2 |         10 |        2 |
|          4 |           1 |        150 |       30 |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Now if I use a `PIVOT` to pivot the PivotValue for each PivotColumn, it's going to group by MainColumn **AND** OtherSum column. ***A pivot groups by every column that isn't part of the pivot***.

So my result set will be split into (MainColumn=1, OtherSum=12), (MainColumn=1, OtherSum=10), (MainColumn=2, OtherSum=5), (MainColumn=2, OtherSum=4), etc... I will get a new line for each of these values. If the OtherSum value was unique for each line, I'd expect 8 lines with a pivot.

If I remove OtherSum from my result set, my result set is just going to group by *MainColumn alone*, so it'll all be on one line for each distinct MainColumn value, since that's the only column the pivot would group by.

If getting the other sum value is important, I can do something like the following:

```
SELECT P.MainColumn,
       Val1A = P.[1],
       Val1B = P.[1] / 5,
       Val2A = P.[2],
       Val2B = P.[2] / 5,
       Val3A = P.[3],
       Val3B = P.[3] / 5
FROM
(
    SELECT MainColumn,
           PivotColumn,
           PivotValue = SUM(SumColumn)
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY MainColumn, PivotColumn
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(PivotValue) FOR PivotColumn IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS P;
```

Comment: Very useful and very thorough explanation. Thank you so much for taking the time!